# Update existing JS associative array with new value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to search **3.30pm** in below array and update the **type** value of the array index in JS

```
0: {time: "2:00pm",type:16}
1: {time: "3:30pm",type:30}
2: {time: "5:00pm",type:90}
```

Any one please suggest the correct way to fix it.

I tried this..

```
 function in_array(array, id) {
    console.log(array);
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        return (array[i][0].time === id)
    }
    return false;
}
$result = in_array(timesShow, $time);
```

But its returning error like

```
movies:620 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined
```

Comment: Remove the `[0]`. The error is telling you that `array[i][0]` is `undefined`. Also, your `for` loop will run at most once, because you unconditionally return.

Comment: Please put complete JSON object in question, that will help to give accurate answers.

Comment: You are mixing php and javascript syntax! Javascript doesn't have associative arrays and in_array is not a built-in javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
   if(array[i].time === id)
   {
       array[i].type='whatever you want to change';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>[Array#Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)</kbd>

```
return array.filter(x=>x.time==id).length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use just the item without another index and return the item, if found.

```js
function getItem(array, id) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].time === id) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
}

var timesShow = [{ time: "2:00pm", type: 16 }, { time: "3:30pm", type: 30 }, { time: "5:00pm", type: 90 }];

console.log(getItem(timesShow, "3:30pm"));
console.log(getItem(timesShow, "2:30pm"));
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
function getItem(array, id) {
    return array.find(o => o.time === id);
}

var timesShow = [{ time: "2:00pm", type: 16 }, { time: "3:30pm", type: 30 }, { time: "5:00pm", type: 90 }];

console.log(getItem(timesShow, "3:30pm"));
console.log(getItem(timesShow, "2:30pm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [
 {time: "2:00pm",type:16},
 {time: "3:30pm",type:30},
 {time: "5:00pm",type:90}
];
obj.forEach(function(ob){
 if(ob.time == "3:30pm") ob.type = 50;
});
console.log(obj)
```

Loop through array object using `forEach` , then check with the time value if matches change type of same object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var obj = [
     {time: "2:00pm",type:16},
     {time: "3:30pm",type:30},
     {time: "5:00pm",type:90}
    ];
    var finalResult = obj.filter(function(d){
     if(d.time == "3:30pm"){d['type'] = 40}
     return d;
    });
console.log(finalResult)
```